# SQL UPDATE statement for a subset of columns: syntax problem

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, syntax-error

I am trying to update cell contents of a subset of columns in an SQLite Table in Python.

```
for i in range(len(list)):
   if list[i] in other_list:
        update_statement = "UPDATE Table \
                            SET Column_1 = Column_1 || ', ({}, {})', \
                            Item count = Item count + {}, \
                            Tot. = {}\
                            WHERE Column_4 = '{}';".format(part_1, part_2, \
                                                           df.iloc[i].at['Count'],\
                                                         2*len(other_list)+2, 'Text')

engine.execute(update_statement)
```

However, I am getting the following syntax error:

```
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "count": syntax error
```

The error arises during the first iteration.
The statement in question is the following:

```
UPDATE Table                             
SET Column_1 = Column_1 || ', (part_1, part_2)', Item count = count + 2, Tot. = 6                            
WHERE Column_4 = 'Text';
```

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: The query as it is should not produce this error. I guess you are using Python to execute it. Post your python code also.

Comment: I edited the question to include part of the preceding Python code. Hope this helps! @forpas

Comment: I guess that `Table` is not the actual name of the table. If it was you get error for this. Also `Item count` is not a valid column name because it contains a space. Enclose it inside backticks or square brackets or double quotes.

Comment: Thanks @forpas. Editing the column name to `Item_count` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Not a SqlLite expert but is Count a keyword in SqlLite? If so maybe alias the Count field. Try:

```
`UPDATE Table SET Column_1 = Column_1 || ', additional_text', theCount = theCount + 2 AS 'Count', Total = 6`
```

WHERE Column_4 = 'Text';
`

Comment: No, it is not a keyword: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: It is however a function in SqlLite. SELECT COUNT(*) , Count(*), count(*) should all work. On the page you sent me to for key words they do not list objects and function as keywords. They do however have a link to setting how they are used and identified. at https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/keyword_check.html - Maybe try theCount = theCount + 2 AS 'Count'

Comment: Count is not a keyword and can be used as an identifier and does not produce any errors.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @forpas, the column name `Item count` was the problem as it contained a space. Re-defining the database's column name to `Item_count` fixed the syntax error.